# How can I make this loop continuously?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops, button

I need to make it so that no user input is required, so the buttons are not required. It should start repeating/ running as soon as the programme is loaded up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var lights=["redlight.jpg","redamberlight.jpg","amberlight.jpg","greenlight.png"]
      var lightscentre= 0
      var timer
      function LightCycle
      {
        if(++lightscentre==30)
          lightscentre=0

          document.images.banner.src = lights[lightscentre]

          timer = setTimeout("LightCycle()",1000)
      }
      function stopCycle()
      {
        clearTimeout(timer)
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="banner1.jpg" name="banner" width=130 height=175>

    <form>
      <input type="button" value="Cycle" name="Cycle" onclick="LightCycle()">
      <input type="button" value="Stop" name="Stop" onclick="stopCycle()">
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

setInterval should do the job, it will run your function at an interval of milliseconds

```
setInterval(LightCycle, 3000);
```

Source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Praveen its my first reply so maybe a little sketchy. A better source (possibly) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval. The snippet was just an untested point in the right direction which I should have made clear.

Comment: Since you understood. I edited the answer to look right... Being a first user, I am giving you a vote up! `:)` Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set an `onload` function.

```
window.onload = LightCycle;
```

This will then start the `LightCycle()` function running when the window is loaded.

You can also use the html attribute `onload` which will run javascript within it.

```
<body onload="LightCycle()"> </body>
```

To complete your full example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var lights=["redlight.jpg","redamberlight.jpg","amberlight.jpg","greenlight.png"]
  var lightscentre= 0
  var timer
  function LightCycle
  {
    if(++lightscentre==30)
      lightscentre=0

    document.images.banner.src = lights[lightscentre]

    timer = setTimeout("LightCycle()",1000)
  }

  window.onload = LightCycle;
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="banner1.jpg" name="banner" width=130 height=175>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not invoking it. To invoke it, please use this:

```
window.onload = LightCycle;
```

Only then it will start the timer. You forgot to add that! `:(`

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you could do that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){LightCycle()});
```

Then when the site has loaded it will call the LightCycle-function.
Or you make in html:

```
<body onLoad="LightCycle()"></body>
```

Comment: @Praveen Kumar try it with onLoad in body tag

Comment: Don't say you are a programmer. `:P` There's something called revisions. Go check and tell me what wrong you made.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar better?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97393/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-orell).

Answer (score 0):

You must activate the function when the window is loaded - so the user action is not required.

For the reason than you can use jquery:

```js
$(function(){ //this will be executed when the window is fully loaded
   LightCycle();
})
```

Comment: Not tagged with jQuery. Please do not post jQuery solutions for questions seeking JavaScript solution.

Comment: You can actually use `window.onload = function () {}`. jQuery is just a library of JavaScript. Not something like a magic.

Answer (score 0):

You've had a bunch of syntax error in your script. However, I've edited it to run:

```js
var lights = [
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bc/Bogensch%C3%BCtzen_in_Ili-Mano_2.jpg/800px-Bogensch%C3%BCtzen_in_Ili-Mano_2.jpg",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3e/Archery_competition.jpg",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e7/3D_game_hunting_0001.jpg/320px-3D_game_hunting_0001.jpg"]

var lightscentre = 0
var timer

function LightCycle() {
  
  if (++lightscentre == 3) {
    
    lightscentre = 0
  
  }

  document.images.banner.src = lights[lightscentre]

  timer = setTimeout("LightCycle()", 1000)
    
}

function stopCycle() {
  
  clearTimeout(timer)
  
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/98/Archery_target.jpg/320px-Archery_target.jpg" name="banner" width=130 height=175>

<form>
 <input type="button" value="Cycle" name="Cycle" onclick="LightCycle()">
 <input type="button" value="Stop" name="Stop" onclick="stopCycle()">
</form>
```

Now, to get this working without using the buttons you just have to call the function in your script. Check out this snippet:

```js
var lights = [
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bc/Bogensch%C3%BCtzen_in_Ili-Mano_2.jpg/800px-Bogensch%C3%BCtzen_in_Ili-Mano_2.jpg",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3e/Archery_competition.jpg",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e7/3D_game_hunting_0001.jpg/320px-3D_game_hunting_0001.jpg"]

var lightscentre = 0
var timer

function LightCycle() {
  
  if (++lightscentre == 3) {
    
    lightscentre = 0
  
  }

  document.images.banner.src = lights[lightscentre]

  timer = setTimeout("LightCycle()", 1000)
    
}

function stopCycle() {
  
  clearTimeout(timer)
  
}

//ADDED LINES!!!
LightCycle();
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/98/Archery_target.jpg/320px-Archery_target.jpg" name="banner" width=130 height=175>

<form>
 <input type="button" value="Stop" name="Stop" onclick="stopCycle()">
</form>
```

Mention the two lines:

```
//ADDED LINES!!!
LightCycle();
```

However, in your given html it would look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var lights=["redlight.jpg","redamberlight.jpg","amberlight.jpg","greenlight.png"]
var lightscentre= 0
var timer
function LightCycle
{
if(++lightscentre==30)
  lightscentre=0

document.images.banner.src = lights[lightscentre]

timer = setTimeout("LightCycle()",1000)
}
function stopCycle()
{
 clearTimeout(timer)
}

//ADDED LINES!!!
LightCycle();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There were a few issues...

The function "LightCycle" was lacking ().
The list was being increased before the first element.
I think using getElementById is better than document.images...
Image element lacked an ID field.
The function can be simply called from body onload, without adding jquery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lights=["1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg","4.jpg"]
    var lightscentre=0;
    var timer;

    function LightCycle() {
        if(lightscentre==4) lightscentre=0

      document.getElementById('banner').src = lights[lightscentre];
        lightscentre++

      timer = setTimeout("LightCycle()",1000)
    }

    function stopCycle()
    {
     clearTimeout(timer)
    }

    LightCycle();
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="LightCycle()">
<img src="1.jpg" name="banner" id="banner" width=130 height=175>

<form>
 <input type="button" value="Cycle" name="Cycle" onclick="LightCycle()">
 <input type="button" value="Stop" name="Stop" onclick="stopCycle()">
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var lights=["redlight.jpg","redamberlight.jpg","amberlight.jpg","greenlight.png"];
var lightscentre= 0;
var timer;

function LightCycle(){
  
  if(++lightscentre==4){
    lightscentre=0;
  }
  document.getElementById('banner').src = lights[lightscentre];
  timer = setTimeout(LightCycle,1000);
}

window.onload = LightCycle();
```

Add ID attribute in the html also.

```html
<img src="banner1.jpg" name="banner" id="banner" width=130 height=175>
```

Answer (score 0):

**In this case the right would use "setInterval".**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
        var lights = ["redlight.jpg", "redamberlight.jpg", "amberlight.jpg", "greenlight.png"],
            index = 0,
            timerID;

        function loadLight() {
            if (index == lights.length) {
                index = 0;
            }

            var banner = document.getElementById("bannerEl");
            if (banner) {
                banner.src = lights[index];
                banner.alt = lights[index];
            }

            index++;
        }

        function startCycle() {
            timerID = setInterval(loadLight, 1000);
        }

        function stopCycle() {
            clearInterval(timerID);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="startCycle();">
    <form id="form1">
        <img src="banner1.jpg" id="bannerEl" width="130" height="175" alt="" />
        <input type="button" value="Cycle" name="Start" onclick="startCycle()" />
        <input type="button" value="Stop" name="Stop" onclick="stopCycle()" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
<body>
<img id="img" src="Chrysanthemum.jpg" name="banner" width=130 height=175>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var lights=["Chrysanthemum.jpg","Desert.jpg","Hydrangeas.jpg"];
    var lightscentre= 0;
    function LightCycle()
    {
        if(++lightscentre==3)
        lightscentre=0;
        document.getElementById('img').src=lights[lightscentre];

    }
    setInterval(function(){
    LightCycle();
    },2000);
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

It will work..!  If you want to stop, then use same approch [ adding timer variable ]